# How can I enable strict sql_mode in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I enable strict `sql_mode` in MySQL?

I want to fetch data from SQL and process the same in `strict` mode.

My current `sql_mode` is:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------------------+
| @@sql_mode             |
+------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try reading the manual section titled [Setting the SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two ways of doing it, using SQL command or changing configuration file. If you set it using SQL command - it will change back after the server is restarted.

Doing it in SQL:

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';`

Doing it in config file:

`[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"`

File location varies depending on your operating system, more on where to find it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Important to note, that you can have multiple modes specified:

`sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

this is especially important when using SQL statement, since it could override your whole mode string.

More stuff about SQL modes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 5):

Do the following:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';
```

Comment: Warning: this overwrites your current `sql_mode` value entirely. If you want to append `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to your current list of settings, this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but they don't work (as-is) for AWS RDS.

If you are running a MySQL server on AWS RDS, then you can't run `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';` straightaway because you don't have the requisite permissions, even with admin-level credentials:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

In AWS RDS, since it's a managed DB service, you don't have access to the `my.cnf` or other configuration files directly - so you can't change the settings there either.

However, note that you can set `sql_mode` at the session-level, but this will be lost across session changes or reboots:

```
mysql> SET SESSION  sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.30 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@session.sql_mode;
+---------------------+
| @@session.sql_mode  |
+---------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES   |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.31 sec)
```

So then how do you change `sql_mode` (or any other parameters for that matter) at a GLOBAL level so that they persist across restarts in AWS RDS MySQL?

You need to create a custom DB `Parameter Group` in RDS (for example, using the web console) like this:

[image: AWS_RDS_CustomParameterGroup]

Then you have to `modify` your RDS instance and apply the newly-created Parameter Group like so:

[image]

Finally, apply your modifications, and reboot (yes, reboot is required) the instance.

And voila, you have your `sql_mode` set as needed, and it persists across reboots now:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                               |
+------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.69 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@global.sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.62 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@session.sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@session.sql_mode                       |
+------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.38 sec)
```